# Passing and returning structs by value or by pointer - are there default guidelines?

Tags: c, memory, struct, conventions

So I've been looking for rule-of-thumb guidelines on two topics:

- When to **return** a struct by value, vs. when to return it by pointer (in the case where the called function has created the struct). E.g:

```c
MyThing make_my_thing() { MyThing m; /* ... */ ; return m; }
// Vs.
MyThing* make_my_thing() { MyThing* m = malloc(sizeof(MyThing)); /* ... */ ; return m; }
```

- When to **pass** a struct by value, vs. when to pass it by pointer

```c
// Assume do_something() doesn't need to mutate m
void do_something(MyThing m) { /* ... */ }  
// Vs.
void do_something(MyThing* m) { /* ... */ }
```

The rule-of-thumb I'm looking for isn't supposed to fit all cases, but should be the default I'm going with in a general case, where the struct isn't very big.

Please note I'm aware different cases may require different solutions - but nonetheless am looking for a basic 'default' convention most developers follow, if one exists.

I have read many questions and answers on this site, and have come up with the following guidelines:

- Default is to **return a struct by value**. Otherwise, we'd have to `malloc` it and mess with its lifecycle management.
- Default is to **pass a struct by pointer** - no need to worry about lifecycle management any more than we already are, and no unnecessary copying of data.

Are these guidelines widely accepted among C programmers? If not, what would be the more generally accepted conventions?

Comment: Passing a `struct` of any size around by value is a lot of dead weight to carry.

Comment: @WeatherVane Disagree.  Passing around a `struct` that is small, maybe even smaller than a pointer is not dead weight.

Comment: @chux of course. My emphasis was intended to be "of any *size*", not "of *any* size".

Answer (score 2):

> Passing and returning structs by value or by pointer guidelines

1) Small size.  When the `struct` is small - I'd say <= twice the size of a pointer, there is little to be lost, size wise, when passing by `struct` by value rather than by a pointer to the `struct`. Simplicity of passing an object by value is gained.

2) Large size.  When the `struct` is large, certainly passing a `pointer to a`struct is more efficient.

3) Numeric object.  When the `struct` has fixed sized allocations and represents a *number*, passing by value just seem to work better.

4) Hiding.  Opaque points to `struct` are a good way to hide the innards of a `struct` and promote object oriented code.

For others cases, I'd say code for clarity - which usually means use a pointer to the `struct` as the that is C idiomatic.

---

For general usage, I find retuning a pointer to a `struct` of little value - aside form one important case: forming a set of functions where the *init* function(s) return an allocated pointer to a `struct`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So as I understand what you're saying, we should pass `struct`s by value when they're small or represent some scalar numeric value. Otherwise, pass by pointer. Is that essentialy your point?

Comment: @AvivCohn That is a good first order conclusion.  Yet not a hard rule as circumstances will push for the other now and then or perhaps other approaches.